# How can I use an env file to pass environment variables into a standalone vscode remote container?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, containers, vscode-remote

I am using a standalone [`Go`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-try-go) vscode remote container for development and would like to load environment variables into the container from a file.

All examples I can find are using Docker Compose and its `env_file` [option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option) but using Docker Compose seems overkill for a single container. Is there any way I can achieve this without using Docker Compose?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the `.devcontainer` directory of your project add a file that declares your environment variables, in this case `.env`:

```
D:.
│   .gitignore
│   README.md
│
├───.devcontainer
│      .env 
│       devcontainer.json
│       Dockerfile
│
└───.vscode
        settings.json
```

`.env`:

```
MY_URL=https://my.com/
MY_SECRET=unicorns
```

Then in your `devcontainer.json` you can define [`runArgs`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_devcontainerjson-reference) that pass the `.env` file as an [`env-file`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) argument to the Docker CLI `run` command. This uses the `${localWorkspaceFolder}` variable that is expanded to the containing directory of the local source code:

`devcontainer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "Go",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "runArgs": [
        "--env-file", "${localWorkspaceFolder}/.devcontainer/.env"
    ], 

    ...
}
```

Comment: `${localWorkspaceFolder}` is not yet supported when using Clone Repository in Container Volume.

Comment: @DavidD. are you saying this doesn't work with Clone Repository in Container Volume at all or that this technique doesn't work but there is an alternative that does work?

Comment: @LarryFoulkrod reading [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference#_variables-in-devcontainerjson) it's written "Not yet supported when using Clone Repository in Container Volume."